# Sublime Text Python Autocomplete

Tags: python, autocomplete, package, sublimetext3

I installed the Package SublimePythonIDE. The Error-Highlightning works fine, but the autocopletion don't work. Here my config:

```
{
    // leave empty string to use default system interpreter
    // e.g. /usr/local/bin/python
    // or "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"
    // if you use virtualenvs, then set the absolute path to the virtualenv's
    // python in your project settings (Project->Edit Project) as in:
    //
    // {
    //     "folders": ...
    //     "settings":
    //     {
    //         "python_interpreter": "/Users/USER/.virtualenvs/PROJECT/bin/python"
    //     }
    // }
    "python_interpreter": "D:/Python27/",

    // make python_open_documentation command output in a view or in the output
    // panel if false
    "open_pydoc_in_view": false,

    // when a doc view is created it will be placed in the active view group
    // if false and only one group exist then a new group will be created
    "create_view_in_same_group": false,

    // Linter settings
    "python_linting": true,
    "python_linter_mark_style": "outline", // "none" or "outline"
    "python_linter_gutter_marks": true,
    "python_linter_gutter_marks_theme": "simple", // see folder gutter_mark_themes
    "pep8": true,
    "pep8_ignore": [],
    "pep8_max_line_length": 80,
    "pyflakes_ignore": []
}
```

what did i wrong?

Comment: might not what you're interested in. But the package anaconda for sublime seems to work good out of the box. It uses the pythonpath to find the interpreter for autocompletion i think. It also does error handeling and linting. Also the standard "did you try turning it off and on again"? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the examples on lines 3 and 4, you'll see that you need to provide the complete path to the Python executable. So, change your line to this:

```
"python_interpreter": "D:\\Python27\\python.exe",
```

and you should be all set.